# Kafka - Deserializing the object in Consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are considering to use Kafka in our for messaging and our applications are developed using Spring. So, we have planned to use spring-kafka.

The producer puts the message as HashMap object into the queue. We have JSON serializer and we assumed that the map will be serialized and put into the queue. And here is the producer config.

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    producer:
        key-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
        value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

On the other hand, we have a listener which listens to the same topic where the producer has published the message. Here is the consumer config:

```
spring:
   kafka:
       consumer:
            group-id: xyz
            key-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
            value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
```

Our listener method:

```
  public void listener(SomeClass abx)
```

We were expecting the json will be de-serialized and an object of type "SomeClass" will be generated. But apparently, it throws de-serialization exception.

We saw few articles and the suggestion was to do something like:

```
 @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, Car> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),
        new JsonDeserializer<>(Car.class));
  }
```

We don't want to write some code for creating the Deserializer. Is there any boilerplate thing which we are missing?
Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Docs for serialization/deserialization: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#serdes
Looks like it should work just with @KafkaListener annotation

Comment: They are suggesting to do something like new JsonDeserializer<>(Bar.class); which I dont want todo, as it will grow when we have more listeners with different types of object

Comment: I don't think it's a problem to have a single configuration class for Kafka. it's just a part of app configuration. But I will watch this issue, cause it's interesting if the solution exists.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for suggestions!!

Comment: You can set the required type using a property - see my answer.

Comment: In case anyone comes here with the same question, I recommend reading answers in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55109508/spring-kafka-no-type-information-in-headers-and-no-default-type-provided

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See [the boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-kafka-extra-props). In particular:

> You can also configure the Spring Kafka JsonDeserializer as follows:
>
> `spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer`
>
> `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.value.default.type=com.example.Invoice`
>
> `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=com.example,org.acme`

Comment: What if I had multiple types? for ex: Invoice, Payment, This and That etc. How does Spring know how to deserialize ?

Comment: There are several options. You can override the properties at the listener level - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-properties - just omit the `spring.kafka.consumer.properties` part. Or you can add a function - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#serdes-type-methods  Or, use a message converter instead and the framework will detect the type from the listener method signature - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#messaging-message-conversion

Answer (score 0):

```
        I was consuming remote Kafka producer event and facing Class not found exception.
        
        so finally I removed configuration form .properties file added below config class in consumer.
  
Here is my application.properties.
spring.application.name=payment-service
server.port=8082
spring.kafka.payment.bootstrap-servers= localhost:9092
spring.kafka.order.consumer.group-id.notification= group-id
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset= latest
spring.kafka.order.topic.create-order=new_order1    


  
        @EnableKafka
        @Configuration("NotificationConfiguration")
        public class CreateOrderConsumerConfig {
            @Value("${spring.kafka.payment.bootstrap-servers}")
            private String bootstrapServers;
            @Value("${spring.kafka.order.consumer.group-id.notification}")
            private String groupId;
            @Bean("NotificationConsumerFactory")
            public ConsumerFactory<String, OrderEvent> createOrderConsumerFactory() {
                Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
                props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
                props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
                props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
                props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
                props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
                props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
                props.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE, "com.swiggy.payment.event.OrderEvent");// this my consumer event class
                props.put(JsonDeserializer.USE_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS,false);
                props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
                props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        
                return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(),
                        new JsonDeserializer<>(OrderEvent.class));
            }
            @Bean("NotificationContainerFactory")
            public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, OrderEvent> createOrderKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
                ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, OrderEvent> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
                factory.setConsumerFactory(createOrderConsumerFactory());
                
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
                return factory;
            }
        }
```