# Transform Kafka Payload to Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have one question about Deserialization in kafka.

I have this String receiving in my kafka application

`Payload: {"post":{"postId":"5e22fac7f7356803e8784172","tags":["a","lovve","asldkjfsbajfdkjlnzx","z"]},"date":"2020-01-18T16:12:50.833423","user":{"userId":"5dfcfd77367c690edd91b2d9"},"reactionType":"unloved"}`

and I have this config in my kafka

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>(
            kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties());

    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            JsonDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,
            "magpie-trending");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

    return props;
}
```

and I have one class with the same code of the Payload, and how at any moment I can transform this in my object?

So I have this Approach too

Hello, everyone, I have this String received by one microservice and working, but i need to transform this string to one specific object, and when I use ObjectMapper to transform The Application returns this exception:

> threw exception; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
>   construct instance of
>   `com.avenuecode.magpie.trending.component.kafka.message.PostMessage`
>   (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from
>   Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

So my Object are:

```
public class ReactionMessage {
 private PostMessage post;
 private String date;
 private UserMessage user;
 private String reactionType;

 @JsonCreator
 public ReactionMessage(@JsonProperty("post") PostMessage post,
                       @JsonProperty("user") UserMessage user,
                       @JsonProperty("date") String date,
                       @JsonProperty("reactionType") String reactionType) {
    this.post = post;
    this.date = date;
    this.user = user;
    this.reactionType = reactionType;
 }

 @JsonCreator
 public ReactionMessage() {
 }
}
```

When I call the mapper are in this method:

```
  @KafkaListener(topics = "reaction-topic", clientIdPrefix = "string", groupId = "magpie-trending")
  public void listenAsObject(ConsumerRecord<String, String> cr,
                           @Payload String payload) throws IOException {
    logger.info("Logger 1 [JSON] received key {}: Type [{}] | Payload: {} | Record: {}", cr.key(),
            typeIdHeader(cr.headers()), payload, cr.toString());

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ReactionMessage message = mapper.readValue(payload, ReactionMessage.class);

}

   private static String typeIdHeader(Headers headers) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(headers.spliterator(), false)
            .filter(header -> header.key().equals("__TypeId__"))
            .findFirst().map(header -> new String(header.value())).orElse("N/A");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your `JsonDeserializer` return the object type you expect

For example, Kafka's built in JSON deserializer only returns `JsonNode`.

The Spring JSON deserializer has extra properties to pass in class names

[Kafka - Deserializing the object in Consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096351/kafka-deserializing-the-object-in-consumer)

Comment: Not working, i don't know why, but when I call ObjectMapper not working too. Problaby is the Kafka Deserialization.

Comment: When I use ObjectMapper to transform the object, returns exception too.

Comment: Works Right now, I need to add JsonCreatorAnnotations on-base classes and works.